# Storing a long array inside of a MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have my database which stores userdata such as username, email, password..

I am currently rewriting the system and trying to improve it/make it more efficient

Currently I need to access an array for a user in the database.

Structure:
username | memberID | email | password | ... |... | skinsInventory |

Now 'skinsInventory is where I want to store this array.
This array could become very big for some users.

Is there a better way to do it or is this the recommended way?
For example some of the users have;
[Database skinsInventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjjMl.png)

But I can expect this to get quite big.
Any better ways to do this?

Help is very appreciated

Comment: How about you create a table for skinsInventory with userId

Comment: What's "long horned cow fish"? But basically it seem like you need a table with a One-to-many relationship (If I understand you correctly)

Comment: can store it as json

Comment: @AlonEitan God knows what that is its a custom uploaded image so i have no idea.